# confusion over default initialisation of instance variables in java

Tags: java, initialization, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of default initialisation. Below is the code I have came up with. Even though I have not set an initial value for variable `x` & `y`, I have instantiated an instance of the class to which the variable belong to. I thought after initialisation, the variable x and y will be set to 0 by default. but when I tested using isVehicleInNegArea method, the method returned false. WHy is this happening? Is there something I am missing? Please help me!

```
public class Vehicle{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehiclev1 = new Vehicle();
        boolean onMap = v1.isVehicleInNegArea();
        System.out.println(onMap);
    }

    int x;
    int y;

    boolean isVehicleInNegArea(){
        return (this.x < 0 || this.y < 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of your primitive `int`(s) is `0` and `0` is not less than `0`. Set the value(s) to something negative like

```
int x = -1;
int y = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's default initialisation sets numeric types to zero, booleans to false, and object types to null.

Answer (score 0):

Although primitive integer types will be set to 0 if not instantiated, by default, you are checking if they are *less than* 0, not less than or equal to. If they are 0, they are not less than 0, they simply are 0. If you want it to default to true, I would suggest setting them to -1 when you instantiate them, or make the check

```
return (this.x <= 0 || this.y <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x; int y; //two global variable.
```

here when you execute this Statement `Vehicl ev1 = new Vehicle();` a `default constuctor` will be excuted and these global variables `x` and `y` will filled with `default` value of `datatype` (int) which is 0. so , `X` and `Y` both will instantiate and initialize with `Zero`.

Now Your Statement

```
(this.x < 0 || this.y < 0); here this.x<0 is equivalent to 0<0 which returns false.
```

> Here `x` and `y` both are intialized with `zero` so first conditional statement (this.x<0) will return `false` and never move to the second statement because a logical `OR` Operator will never checks the second condition if first statement returns false.

so your Method  `boolean isVehicleInNegArea()` will returns `false`.

Thank You..